# Is there a proof that $\int \frac {dx}{x}=\ln |x|+c$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, numerical-methods, education

Is there a proof that $$\int \frac {dx}{x}= \ln|x|+c$$
for $x\neq 0$

I would be interest for any replies or any comment.

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln$?

Comment: neip-logarithm , logarithm function

Comment: The problem here is definitions. Sometimes, this result is a definition, in which case the result that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ is a theorem. Other times, we define $e^x$ such that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$, and then define $\ln$ to be the inverse of that. Then this result is a theorem. (In both cases the proof comes from the inverse function theorem.) Other alternatives exist, too, for instance you can start all the way down at $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ and then try to define general exponentiation from the ground up. It just depends on what you want to take for granted.

Comment: The simple way to test an alleged antiderivative is to take its derivative.

Comment: no, i want a proof show us that the antiderivative of 1/x is ln|x|

Comment: The problem is that $\ln x$ is sometimes defined as the antiderivative, in which case the proof is trivial - so we need to know where you are starting from so we can help you. It is easy to prove - integrating from $1$ to a positive limit $y$ - that the antiderivative has the properties of a logarithm - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: the question is for example , why 0 !=1 ?

Comment: Then why ln'(x)=1/x

Comment: ok, thank you for editing question, it's exactly what i want

Answer (score 2):

If we accept that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, then we can simply use implicit differentiation.

$$\begin{align}y&=\ln x\\x&=e^y\\\frac{d}{dx}x&=\frac d {dx}e^y\\1&=\frac{dy}{dx}e^y\\\frac 1{e^y}&=\frac{dy}{dx}\\\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac 1 x\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you , but you are wondred that y=lnx, should be ignor that there is a function called ln

Comment: @user51189 You can say "$e^x$ is monotone, so it has an inverse that we will denote by $\ln$", if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to find the antiderivative of $\cfrac 1x$ - it doesn't come in the pattern of derivatives of powers, because differentiating a constant always gives zero. When we look at the function we realise we will have a problem if our interval of integration includes zero, so we have to avoid that. And we see that this is an odd function, so if we have negative limits, we change them to positive and change the sign. So we deal with positive limits throughout and adapt to negative limits later.

Let's start thinking about the properties of $$\int_a^x \cfrac 1y dy=\int_a^1 \cfrac 1y dy+\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy=c+\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy$$ so we might as well have the lower limit $1$ and consider $$L(x)=\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy$$

We note that $L(1)=0$ and $$L(ab)=\int_1^{ab} \cfrac 1x dx=\int_1^a \cfrac 1x dx+\int_a^{ab} \cfrac 1x dx=L(a)+L(b)$$ after a simple substitution in the second integral.

Then the properties of a logarithm are established and the base is the number $e$ such that $L(e)=1$. So maybe you are looking for a proof that this $e$ is the same one you get by some other route?

This was too long for a comment.

Comment: (+1) This is a good way to look at it - proving first that the antiderivative is logarithm*ic*.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question where the absolute value comes in?

for $x > 0$, $|x| = x$, in which case

$D_x \ln |x| = D_x \ln x = \dfrac 1 x$

for $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$, and

$D_x \ln |x| = D_x \ln (-x) = -1 \cdot \dfrac 1 {-x} = \dfrac 1 x$

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm can be defined by
$$\ln x=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]x-1).$$
Then deriving,
$$(\ln x)'=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac1nx^{1/n-1}=\frac1x.$$
(This is not a rigorous proof.)

Comment: who is would be like to answer this question, just to see the tags of question related

Answer (score 1):

In all fairness, the formula $\displaystyle\int x^{-1}dx=\log |x|+c$ is incorrect, or at least is unexhaustive. The correct formula is  $$=\begin{cases}\log x+c_1;x>0\\\log(-x)+c_2;x<0\end{cases}$$ where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

The point is that the singular point at $x=0$ makes the solution space of $xy'=1$ two dimensional instead of $1$ dimensional, as one would expect in a first degree equation.

Comment: Tam  , i  think that i said x\neq 0

Comment: I think his point is that $c_1$ need not be equal to $c_2$. Though if that is his point, "degrees" and "singularities" don't really help to clarify.

Comment: @user51189 I'm not following. I'm having crossed feelings about the nickname "Tam", too.