# integration of $1/x$ a counterexample to the rule

Tags: calculus, integration

We know that the integration of $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\log\left(|x|\right)$+$c$ with $x\neq 0$ , but if we go by normal rule then it becomes $\infty$.
Is this a counterexample to the rule of $\;x^{n+1}\big/(n+1)\;$ or am I missing something? Now according to comments i amasking how to prove that derrivative of $log(x)=1/x$ any method would do.

Comment: It is a counterexample, yes.

Comment: The way understand it is that the rule is true for $n\neq -1$, so I would say (technically) no, it is not a counter example.

Comment: Then how will you prove  that integration is log(x)

Comment: I believe it is given as a definition (in most?) text books, in other words $\ln x : = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$, if I recall correctly.

Comment: So, in that sense, you do not "prove it" per se.

Comment: @probablyme Is $\ln$ ever really defined this way? That seems extremely weird - how do you prove that it is a logarithm, then?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Like I said, text books (basic calculus), and Wikipedia seems to agree that you can do it [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions). I don't claim that it is good or bad; I claim to witness its existence.

Comment: Actually, while defining the formula we specifically write while n is not equal to -1. So the 'normal' method can't be applied. Remember 1/0 is undefined.

Comment: @probablyme: Haha, clever.  However, note that OP did not state the condition $n \not= 1$, so it is a counterexample to OP's statement. :-P

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question :http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071183/230303

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a counterexample.  I'd say it's a point where the rule breaks down.  As 1/0 is undefined $\int x^n = x^{n+1}/(n+1)$ is undefined when $n = -1$ is all.  But as calculus is all about limits $\int x^n$ also = $\lim_{n\rightarrow -1} x^{n+1}/(n+1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow } x^{n}/(n)= \ln x$

Comment: Counterexample and/or the proof?  One or Two question?

Comment: @fleablood: Well, now we're getting philosophical. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung Philosophical is not a problem.  But what's the asker want?

Comment: @NgChungTak: Indeed usually the problem is that the asker doesn't really know what he wants. If he had stated the rule unambiguously, specifying what is $x$ and what is $n$ and what $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ is supposed to be, then we can (almost always) unambiguously answer whether it is a correct rule or a false rule with a counterexample.

Comment: When we differentiate using $y=x^n$, we can't at anyway use $a^0$ or constant or $\infty$ (as \infty can be treated as a constant) to give $\frac{dy}{dx}=1/x$ so there is a reason why $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x}\neq \infty$

Comment: The rule does state where $x^{n+1}/(n+1)$ is defined.  So it's not a counter example  But not $n$ need not by an integer.  $\int x^{1/n}$ also is $x^{1 + 1/n}/(1 + 1/n)$ so my comment about limits is not off base.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming $\ln$ is defined as the logarithm with base $e$, and that $e$ is defined as $\lim_{v\rightarrow 0}(1+v)^{1\over v}$; also, I'm sweeping a bunch of stuff (mainly proofs that the relevant functions are continuous, and that $e$ exists) under the rug in the interests of readability.

---

It's a little easier (in my opinion) to turn it around, and prove that the derivative of $\ln$ is $1\over x$.

By definition, the derivative of natural log is $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\ln(x+h)-\ln(x)\over h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\ln(1+{h\over x})\over h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\ln((1+{h\over x})^{1\over h}).$$ Set $u={h\over x}$; we can rewrite this limit as $$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}[\ln(1+u)^{1\over ux}]={1\over x}\ln\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}[(1+u)^{1\over u}].$$ But by the definition of $e$, this is just ${1\over x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\log(x)$ is frequently defined by that integral. The only other definition that you ever see is that it's the function $f(x)$ that satisfies $e^{f(x)}=f(e^{x})=x$. We can then use the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ and the inverse fuction theorem to conclude that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Note that this just pushes things back: how do we know the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$?

Comment: You're right. While studying calculus, we learn logarithms as the inverse of the exponential function. However, while studying analysis which seeks to build a rigorous foundation we study logarithms before exponents, even though that wasn't the historical way of development. And, logarithms are defined by that integral.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed it does. It's a matter of picking your battles, and personally I think the most reasonable thing to do is define the logarithm by this integral.

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\exp(x)$ can be defined as the function satisfying $y' = y$ and $f(0) = 1$. Uniqueness isn't trivial to prove but not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :if you seek for a proof  just to look the following  [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1071212/156150) by "Mark Bennet" for  [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071183/230303)

**Answer**:
Suppose we want to find the antiderivative of $\cfrac 1x$ - it doesn't come in the pattern of derivatives of powers, because differentiating a constant always gives zero. When we look at the function we realise we will have a problem if our interval of integration includes zero, so we have to avoid that. And we see that this is an odd function, so if we have negative limits, we change them to positive and change the sign. So we deal with positive limits throughout and adapt to negative limits later.

Let's start thinking about the properties of $$\int_a^x \cfrac 1y dy=\int_a^1 \cfrac 1y dy+\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy=c+\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy$$ so we might as well have the lower limit $1$ and consider $$L(x)=\int_1^x \cfrac 1y dy$$

We note that $L(1)=0$ and $$L(ab)=\int_1^{ab} \cfrac 1x dx=\int_1^a \cfrac 1x dx+\int_a^{ab} \cfrac 1x dx=L(a)+L(b)$$ after a simple substitution in the second integral.

Then the properties of a logarithm are established and the base is the number $e$ such that $L(e)=1$. So maybe you are looking for a proof that this $e$ is the same one you get by some other route?

This was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln\left|x\right|+c$
The proof is as shown:

when $y=ln(x)$ then $x=e^y$

Using implicit differentiation of
$x=e^y$ gives $e^y\frac{dy}{dx}=1$

Replacing $x=e^y$ will give you $x\frac{dy}{dx}=1$

Dividing both sides by x thus gives you $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$ when $y=ln(x)$

**To find derivitive of $y=log_a(x)$ where $a$ is a constant, I can use the similar method:**

when $y=log_a(x)$ then $x=a^y$

Using implicit differentiation of $x=a^y$ gives $ln(a)a^y\frac{dy}{dx}=1$

replacing $x=a^y$ gives $ln(a)x\frac{dy}{dx}=1$

Dividing both sides by $x\cdot ln(a)$ gives: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\cdot ln(a)}$$

P.S: Explanation derived from hassee mathematics HL textbook (core)

Comment: so when $a=10$ then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\cdot ln(10)}$$